# bootstrap-datepicker and django template, an easy way

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-datepicker

I would like to use date picker in my template. Is there a way to omit stuff in `forms.py` and simply do something like:

```
<tr class="new">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <td>
            <input size="10" type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="{{ form.date }}">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#date").datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy", autoclose: true});
            </script>
        </td>
        ...
```

That is, to use the `{{ form.date }}` as a name in input for example? Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: try install django-crispy-forms with pip ?

Comment: it still requires using forms.py

Comment: Are you able to use crispy form ? if yes i can answer you ...

Comment: i can but im not familiar with it

Comment: Ok you using bootstrap now ?

Comment: yes i am using it

Comment: I have put for you one answer. Hope this help you...Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom input fields with HTML or Bootstrap, as long as you let Django know, which input field in your `forms.py` you mean. You do this by specifying the proper `id` to the HTML input field.

For example, if you have a form which takes a DateField in your `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

class YourForm(forms.Form):

    some_date = forms.DateField()
    # ... more stuff
```

Then, your proper `id` for the input would be `id='id_some_date'`.
(And `name` would be `name='some_date'`.)

EDIT: In your case, you can try `id='{{ form.date.id_for_label }}'`, so you do not need to hardcode the `id`.

When the template is rendered, `{{ form.date }}` would render to the HTML input form, which is the form you specified in `forms.py`.

Comment: it actually worked just by adding name="date", without any changes in forms.py... mysterious but at least works somehow